# connecting from tpye A device to b/g/n wirless network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, 802.11

i have an old ubiquiti nanostaion5-Loc which seems to only support 802.11A
and a tp-link w8960n router supporting b/g/n
im sure the nanostation can be used as a wireless bridge but can i use it to connect to my tplink router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not compatible.

- 802.11a is for 5 GHz; 802.11b/g are for 2.4 GHz. (802.11n could be either.)
- NanoStation 5 only works in the 5 GHz band. See [datasheet](https://dl.ubnt.com/ns5_datasheet.pdf).
- TP-Link W8960N only works in the 2.4 GHz band. See [datasheet](https://www.tp-link.com/au/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8960N.html#specifications).

This can be guessed from supported protocols:

- For example, if a device supports `a/b/g/n`, that means it's dual-band.
- But if it supports just `a/n` or just `a`, then it's certainly 5 GHz-only.
- If it supports just `b/g` or `b/g/n`, it's 2.4 GHz-only.